# access denied in createnamedpipe in client side

Tags: c, windows-services, named-pipes

I get an access_denied while creating named pipe in client side. The serves side of the the named pipe is a windows service, I didn't get this kind of error while it wasn't running as windows service though. So any thoughts in accessing the pipe from windows service?


This how i created my named pipe in the server side:

```
hCreateNamedPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
                TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\GTimeOpt"),
                PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,
                PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
                dwszOutputBuffer,
                dwszInputBuffer,
                0,
                NULL);
```

while this is how I created the named pipe in client side:

```
hCreateFile = CreateFile(
                    TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\GTimeOpt"),
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    NULL);
```

Comment: wasn't there some caveat that named pipes were to NOT have any backslashes in the name except for the very first character.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that, but that's how things according to the documentation in msdn